# Which algorithm of triangulation is used by Opengl?

Tags: triangulation

Which the algorithm of triangulation is the faster among existings? does he exist with complexity O(N)? Which algorithm is used by OpenGl? I implemented the algorithm with dynamic cache of searching triangle, but it is slow

Comment: I understand that Opengl is the specification, by does some implementation of triamgulation exist

Comment: You will need to give some context. What are you trying to triangulate? A polygon? There's a lot of different things that can be triangulated. And what does OpenGL have to do with it? OpenGL does not have any functions for triangulation. Well, it used to be able to render polygons, but that's deprecated, and it only supports triangles now. And even those polygons had to be convex, which makes the triangulation trivial.

Comment: no,i want to triangulate arbitrary set of points

Comment: I want to know some implementation of triangulation  - the faster algorithm, which will works good on big data ( set of points )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an incremental algorithm and a monster curve to presort the points. Translate x- and y coordinate to a binary and concatenate it and sort the points. I think it can work with other triangulation but I recommend to try it with bowyer-watson. You can look into CGAL sourcecode it uses a monster curve and bowyer-watson.

Comment: Thanks, in my variant triangulation i use the special cache grid of triangles